# Что сделать, чтобы блок был размером с изображением?

Tags: css

У меня возникла проблема, я вставил верхний блок(site-header) изображение, но на устройствах под этим изображением создаётся дополнительное пространство, а на компьютерах изображение обрезается на половину. Я хочу, что бы на всех устройствах этот блок выводился полномасштабным изображением без обрезаний и дополнительного пространства, но не понимаю, как это сделать. Попробовал 
Max-width:100%;
Height: auto; 
И это почему-то не работает, как и куча других вариантов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то тебе нужно изменить в ``.site-header `` следующее: ``background-size: 100%;`` на ``background-size: cover;``

Comment: @LetsDrum изображение стаёт во весь блок, но обрезается с левой части

Comment: Ваша картинка так или иначе будет обрезаться при изменении соотношения сторон, но чтобы это смотрелось норм, вам нужно сделать, как сказали выше, `background-size: cover` (заполняет весь блок, обрезая картинку, если не устраивает попробуйте `background-size: contain`, тогда картинка всегда будет отображаться полностью, не нарушая своих пропорций), а также всегда выравнивать картинку по центру `background-position: center`